# Web crawler uses lots of memory

Tags: java, web-scraping, memory-optimization

I am developing a web crawler application. When I run the program for more than 3 hours, the program runs out of memory. I should run the program for more that 2-3 days non-stop to get the results I need.  How is this program using memory inefficiently?

**seeds.txt**

> ```
> http://www.stanford.edu
> http://www.archive.org
> ```

**WebCrawler.java**

```java
package pkg.crawler;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.jsoup.HttpStatusException;
import org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;


public class WebCrawler {

public static Queue <LinkNodeLight> queue = new PriorityBlockingQueue <> (); // priority queue
public static final int n_threads = 5;                                 // amount of threads
private static Set<String> processed = new LinkedHashSet <> ();         // set of processed urls
private PrintWriter out;                                                // output file
private PrintWriter err;                                                // error file
private static Integer cntIntra = new Integer (0);                              // counters for intra- links in the queue
private static Integer cntInter = new Integer (0);                              // counters for inter- links in the queue
private static Integer dub = new Integer (0);                                   // amount of skipped urls

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Running web crawler: " + new Date());

    WebCrawler webCrawler = new WebCrawler();
    webCrawler.createFiles();
    try (Scanner in = new Scanner(new File ("seeds.txt"))) {
        while (in.hasNext()) {
            webCrawler.enque(new LinkNode (in.nextLine().trim()));
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    webCrawler.processQueue();
    webCrawler.out.close();
    webCrawler.err.close();
}

public void processQueue(){
    /* run in threads */
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override 
        public void run() {
            /* queue may be empty but process is not finished, that's why we need to check if any links are being processed */
            while (true) {
                LinkNode link = deque();
                if (link == null)
                    continue;
                link.setStartTime(new DateTime());
                boolean process = processLink(link);
                link.setEndTime(new DateTime());
                if (!process)
                    continue;
                /* print the data to the csv file */
                if (link.getStatus() != null && link.getStatus().equals(LinkNodeStatus.OK)) {
                    synchronized(out) {
                        out.println(getOutputLine(link));
                        out.flush();
                    }
                } else {
                    synchronized(err) {
                        err.println(getOutputLine(link));
                        err.flush();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    };
    /* run n_threads threads which perform dequeue and process */
    LinkedList <Thread> threads = new LinkedList <> ();
    for (int i = 0; i < n_threads; i++) {
        threads.add(new Thread(r));
        threads.getLast().start();
    }
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


/* returns true if link was actually processed */
private boolean processLink(LinkNode inputLink) {
    String url = getUrlGeneralForm(inputLink);
    boolean process = true;
    synchronized (processed) {
        if (processed.contains(url)) {
            process = false;
            synchronized (dub) {dub++;}
        } else
            processed.add(url);
    }
    /* start processing only if the url have not been processed yet or not being processed */
    if (process) {
        System.out.println("Processing url " + url);
        List<LinkNodeLight> outputLinks = parseAndWieghtResults(inputLink);
        for (LinkNodeLight outputLink : outputLinks) {
            String getUrlGeneralForumOutput = getUrlGeneralForm(outputLink);
            /* add the new link to the queue only if it has not been processed yet */
            process = true;
            synchronized (processed) {
                if (processed.contains(getUrlGeneralForumOutput)) {
                    process = false;
                    synchronized (dub) {dub++;}
                }
            }
            if (process) {
                enque(outputLink);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void enque(LinkNodeLight link){
    link.setEnqueTime(new DateTime());
    /* the add method requires implicit priority */
    synchronized (queue) {
        if (link.interLinks)
            synchronized (cntInter) {cntInter++;}
        else
            synchronized (cntIntra) {cntIntra++;}
      //queue.add(link, 100 - (int)(link.getWeight() * 100.f));
        queue.add(link);
    }
}


/**
 * Picks an element from the queue
 * @return top element from the queue or null if the queue is empty
 */
LinkNode deque(){
    /* link must be checked */
    LinkNode link = null;
    synchronized (queue) {
        link = (LinkNode) queue.poll();
        if (link != null) {
            link.setDequeTime(new DateTime());
            if (link.isInterLinks())
                synchronized (cntInter) {cntInter--;}
            else
                synchronized (cntIntra) {cntIntra--;}
        }
    }
    return link;
}

private void createFiles() {
    /* create output file */
    try {
        out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("CrawledURLS.csv", false)));
        out.println(generateHeaderFile());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    /* create error file */
    try {
        err = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("CrawledURLSERROR.csv", false)));
        err.println(generateHeaderFile());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
/**
 * formats the string so it can be valid entry in csv file
 * @param s
 * @return
 */
private static String format(String s) {
    // replace " by ""
    String ret = s.replaceAll("\"", "\"\"");
    // put string into quotes
    return "\"" + ret + "\"";
}
/**
 * Creates the line that needs to be written in the outputfile
 * @param link
 * @return
 */
public static String getOutputLine(LinkNode link){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append(link.getParentLink()!=null ? format(link.getParentLink().getUrl()) : "");
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(link.getParentLink()!=null ? link.getParentLink().getIpAdress() : "");
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(link.getParentLink()!=null ? link.getParentLink().linkProcessingDuration() : "");
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(format(link.getUrl()));
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(link.getDomain());
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(link.getIpAdress());
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(link.isInterLinks());
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(link.getWeight());
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(Util.formatDate(link.getEnqueTime()));
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(Util.formatDate(link.getDequeTime()));
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(link.waitingInQueue());
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(queue.size());
    /* Inter and intra links in queue */
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(cntIntra.toString());
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(cntInter.toString());
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(dub);
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(new Date ());
    /* URL size*/
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(link.getSize());
    /* HTML file
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append(link.getFileName());*/
    /* add HTTP error */
    builder.append(",");
    if (link.getParseException() != null) {
        if (link.getParseException() instanceof HttpStatusException)
            builder.append(((HttpStatusException) link.getParseException()).getStatusCode());
        if (link.getParseException() instanceof SocketTimeoutException)
            builder.append("Time out");
        if (link.getParseException() instanceof MalformedURLException)
            builder.append("URL is not valid");
        if (link.getParseException() instanceof UnsupportedMimeTypeException)
            builder.append("Unsupported mime type: " + ((UnsupportedMimeTypeException)link.getParseException()).getMimeType());
    }
    return builder.toString();

}

/**
 * generates the Header for the file
 * @param link
 * @return
 */
private String generateHeaderFile(){
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.append("Seed URL");
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append("Seed IP");
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append("Process Duration");
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append("Link URL");
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append("Link domain");
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append("Link IP");
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append("isIntern");
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append("Weight");
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append("Enque Time");
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append("Deque Time");
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append("Waiting in the Queue");
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append("QueueSize");
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append("Intra in queue");
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append("Inter in queue");
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append("Dublications skipped");
    /* time was printed, but no header was */
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append("Time");
    /* URL size*/
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append("Size bytes");
    /* HTTP errors */
    builder.append(",");
    builder.append("HTTP error");
    return builder.toString();

}



String getUrlGeneralForm(LinkNodeLight link){
    String url = link.getUrl();
    if (url.endsWith("/")){
        url = url.substring(0, url.length() - 1);
    }
    return url;
}


private List<LinkNodeLight> parseAndWieghtResults(LinkNode inputLink) {
    List<LinkNodeLight> outputLinks = HTMLParser.parse(inputLink);
    if (inputLink.hasParseException()) {
        return outputLinks;
    } else {
        return URLWeight.weight(inputLink, outputLinks);
    }
}
}
```

**HTMLParser.java**

```java
package pkg.crawler;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Formatter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.security.*;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;


public class HTMLParser {

private static final int READ_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISSECS = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
private static HashMap <String, Integer> filecounter = new HashMap<> ();


public static List<LinkNodeLight> parse(LinkNode inputLink){
    List<LinkNodeLight> outputLinks = new LinkedList<>();
    try {
        inputLink.setIpAdress(IpFromUrl.getIp(inputLink.getUrl()));
        String url = inputLink.getUrl();
        if (inputLink.getIpAdress() != null) {
            url.replace(URLWeight.getHostName(url), inputLink.getIpAdress());
        }
        Document parsedResults =  Jsoup
                .connect(url)
                .timeout(READ_TIMEOUT_IN_MILLISSECS)
                .get();
        inputLink.setSize(parsedResults.html().length());
        /* IP address moved here in order to speed up the process */
        inputLink.setStatus(LinkNodeStatus.OK);
        inputLink.setDomain(URLWeight.getDomainName(inputLink.getUrl()));
        if (true) {
            /* save the file to the html */
            String filename = parsedResults.title();//digestBig.toString(16) + ".html";
            if (filename.length() > 24) {
                filename = filename.substring(0, 24);
            }
            filename = filename.replaceAll("[^\\w\\d\\s]", "").trim();
            filename = filename.replaceAll("\\s+",  " ");

            if (!filecounter.containsKey(filename)) {
                filecounter.put(filename, 1);
            } else {
                Integer tmp = filecounter.remove(filename);
                filecounter.put(filename, tmp + 1);
            }
            filename = filename + "-" + (filecounter.get(filename)).toString() + ".html";
            filename = Paths.get("downloads", filename).toString();
            inputLink.setFileName(filename);
            /* use md5 of url as file name */
            try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filename)))) {
                out.println("<!--" + inputLink.getUrl() + "-->");
                out.print(parsedResults.html());
                out.flush();
                out.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        String tag;
        Elements tagElements;
        List<LinkNode> result;


        tag = "a[href";
        tagElements = parsedResults.select(tag);
        result = toLinkNodeObject(inputLink, tagElements, tag);
        outputLinks.addAll(result);


        tag = "area[href";
        tagElements = parsedResults.select(tag);
        result = toLinkNodeObject(inputLink, tagElements, tag);
        outputLinks.addAll(result);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        inputLink.setParseException(e);
        inputLink.setStatus(LinkNodeStatus.ERROR);
    }

    return outputLinks;
}


static List<LinkNode> toLinkNodeObject(LinkNode parentLink, Elements tagElements, String tag) {
    List<LinkNode> links = new LinkedList<>();
    for (Element element : tagElements) {

        if(isFragmentRef(element)){
            continue;
        }

        String absoluteRef = String.format("abs:%s", tag.contains("[") ? tag.substring(tag.indexOf("[") + 1, tag.length()) : "href");
        String url = element.attr(absoluteRef);

        if(url!=null && url.trim().length()>0) {
            LinkNode link = new LinkNode(url);
            link.setTag(element.tagName());
            link.setParentLink(parentLink);
            links.add(link);
        }
    }
    return links;
}

static boolean isFragmentRef(Element element){
    String href = element.attr("href");
    return href!=null && (href.trim().startsWith("#") || href.startsWith("mailto:"));
}
}
```

**Util.java**

```java
package pkg.crawler;

import java.util.Date;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;


public class Util {

private static DateTimeFormatter formatter;
static {



    formatter =   DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS");


}


public static String linkToString(LinkNode inputLink){


    return String.format("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s",
            inputLink.getUrl(),
            inputLink.getWeight(),
            formatDate(inputLink.getEnqueTime()),
            formatDate(inputLink.getDequeTime()),
            differenceInMilliSeconds(inputLink.getEnqueTime(), inputLink.getDequeTime()),
            inputLink.getParentLink()==null?"":inputLink.getParentLink().getUrl()
    );
}

public static String linkToErrorString(LinkNode inputLink){

    return String.format("%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s",
            inputLink.getUrl(),
            inputLink.getWeight(),
            formatDate(inputLink.getEnqueTime()),
            formatDate(inputLink.getDequeTime()),
            inputLink.getParentLink()==null?"":inputLink.getParentLink().getUrl(),
            inputLink.getParseException().getMessage()
    );
}


public static String formatDate(DateTime date){
    return formatter.print(date);
}

public static long differenceInMilliSeconds(DateTime dequeTime, DateTime enqueTime){
    return (dequeTime.getMillis()- enqueTime.getMillis());
}

public static int differenceInSeconds(Date enqueTime, Date dequeTime){
    return (int)((dequeTime.getTime()/1000) - (enqueTime.getTime()/1000));
}

public static int differenceInMinutes(Date enqueTime, Date dequeTime){
    return (int)((dequeTime.getTime()/60000) - (enqueTime.getTime()/60000));
}

}
```

**URLWeight.java**

```java
package pkg.crawler;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class URLWeight {

public static List<LinkNodeLight> weight(LinkNode sourceLink, List<LinkNodeLight> links) {

    List<LinkNodeLight> interLinks = new LinkedList<>();
    List<LinkNodeLight> intraLinks = new LinkedList<>();

    for (LinkNodeLight link : links) {
        if (isIntraLink(sourceLink, link)) {
            intraLinks.add(link);
            link.setInterLinks(false);
        } else {
            interLinks.add(link);
            link.setInterLinks(true);
        }
    }

    float linkWeight = 0f;
    if (interLinks.size() > intraLinks.size()) {

        linkWeight = (float) (Math
                .round(100.0 * ((((float) interLinks.size() + (float) intraLinks.size()) - (float) intraLinks
                        .size()) / ((float) interLinks.size() + (float) intraLinks.size()) * (0.7f))) / 100.0);
        for (LinkNodeLight link : interLinks) {
            link.setWeight(linkWeight);
        }

        // intra puan
        //
        linkWeight = (float) (Math
                .round(100.0 * ((((float) interLinks.size() + (float) intraLinks.size()) - (float) intraLinks
                        .size()) / ((float) interLinks.size() + (float) intraLinks.size()) * (0.3f))) / 100.0);
        for (LinkNodeLight link : intraLinks) {
            link.setWeight(linkWeight);
        }

    } else {
    // if (interLinks.size()<intraLinks.size())

        // inter puan// - (Burada Mï¿½N inter)
        linkWeight = (float) (Math
                .round(100.0 * ((((float) interLinks.size() + (float) intraLinks.size()) - (float) interLinks
                        .size()) / ((float) interLinks.size() + (float) intraLinks.size()) * (0.7f))) / 100.0);
        for (LinkNodeLight link : interLinks) {
            link.setWeight(linkWeight);
        }

        // intra puan
        linkWeight = (float) (Math.round(100.0 * ((((float) interLinks.size() + (float) intraLinks.size()) - (float) interLinks
                .size()) / ((float) interLinks.size() + (float) intraLinks.size()) * (0.3f))) / 100.0);
        for (LinkNodeLight link : intraLinks) {
            link.setWeight(linkWeight);

        }

    }
    List<LinkNodeLight> list = new LinkedList<>();
    list.addAll(interLinks);
    list.addAll(intraLinks);

    return list;
}


static boolean isIntraLink(LinkNodeLight sourceLink, LinkNodeLight link){

    String parentDomainName = getHostName(sourceLink.getUrl());

    String childDomainName = getHostName(link.getUrl());
    return parentDomainName.equalsIgnoreCase(childDomainName);
}

public static String getHostName(String url) {
    if(url == null){
    //  System.out.println("Deneme");
        return "";

    }

    String domainName = new String(url);

    int index = domainName.indexOf("://");
    if (index != -1) {

        domainName = domainName.substring(index + 3);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < domainName.length(); i++)
        if (domainName.charAt(i) == '?' || domainName.charAt(i) == '/') {
            domainName = domainName.substring(0, i);
            break;
        }

    /*if (index != -1) {

        domainName = domainName.substring(0, index);
    }*/

    /* have to keep www in order to do replacements with IP */
    //domainName = domainName.replaceFirst("^www.*?\\.", "");

    return domainName;
}
public static String getDomainName(String url) {
    String [] tmp= getHostName(url).split("\\.");
    if (tmp.length == 0)
        return "";
    return tmp[tmp.length - 1];
}


}
```

**PingTaskManager.java**

```java
package pkg.crawler;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class PingTaskManager {

private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(100);

public  static void ping (LinkNode e) {
    executor.submit(new PingTaks(e));
}


}

class PingTaks implements Runnable {
 private LinkNode link;
public PingTaks( LinkNode link ) {

}

@Override
public void run() {
    /* link.ping(); */      
}


}
```

**LinkNodeStatus.java**

```java
package pkg.crawler;

public enum LinkNodeStatus {
OK,
ERROR

}
```

**LinkNodeLight.java**

```java
package pkg.crawler;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

public class LinkNodeLight implements Comparable<LinkNodeLight> {
protected String url;
protected float weight;
protected DateTime enqueTime;
protected boolean interLinks;

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public float getWeight() {
    return weight;
}

public void setWeight(float weight) {
    this.weight = weight;
}

public DateTime getEnqueTime() {
    return enqueTime;
}


public LinkNodeLight(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public boolean isInterLinks() {
    return interLinks;
}

public void setInterLinks(boolean interLinks) {
    this.interLinks = interLinks;
}

public void setEnqueTime(DateTime enqueTime) {
    this.enqueTime = enqueTime;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(LinkNodeLight link) {

    if (this.weight < link.weight) return 1;
     else if (this.weight > link.weight) return -1;
        return 0;

    }
}
```

**LinkNode.java**

```java
package pkg.crawler;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Date;



import org.joda.time.DateTime;


public class LinkNode extends LinkNodeLight{
public LinkNode(String url) {
    super(url);
}

private String tag;
private LinkNode parentLink;
private IOException parseException = null; // initialize parse Exception with null
private float weight;
private DateTime dequeTime;
private DateTime startTime;
private DateTime endTime;
private LinkNodeStatus status;
private String ipAdress;
private int size;
private String filename;
private String domain;

public DateTime getStartTime() {
    return startTime;
}

public void setStartTime(DateTime startTime) {
    this.startTime = startTime;
}

public DateTime getEndTime() {
    return endTime;
}

public void setEndTime(DateTime endTime) {
    this.endTime = endTime;
}

public DateTime getDequeTime() {
    return dequeTime;
}

public String getTag() {
    return tag;
}

public LinkNode getParentLink() {
    return parentLink;
}

public Exception getParseException() {
    return parseException;
}

public boolean hasParseException(){
    return parseException!=null;
}


public void setDequeTime(DateTime dequeTime) {
    this.dequeTime = dequeTime;
}

public void setTag(String tag) {
    this.tag = tag;
}

public void setParentLink(LinkNode parentLink) {
    this.parentLink = parentLink;
}

public void setParseException(IOException parseException) {
    this.parseException = parseException;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
        return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    LinkNode link = (LinkNode) o;

    if (url != null ? !url.equals(link.url) : link.url != null) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return url != null ? url.hashCode() : 0;
}

public long waitingInQueue(){
    return Util.differenceInMilliSeconds( dequeTime,enqueTime );
}

public long linkProcessingDuration(){
    return Util.differenceInMilliSeconds( endTime,startTime );
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("LinkNode{");
    sb.append("url='").append(url).append('\'');
    sb.append(", score=").append(weight);
    sb.append(", enqueTime=").append(enqueTime);
    sb.append(", dequeTime=").append(dequeTime);
    sb.append(", tag=").append(tag);
    if(parentLink!=null) {
        sb.append(", parentLink=").append(parentLink.getUrl());
    }
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
}

public void setStatus(LinkNodeStatus status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public LinkNodeStatus getStatus(){
    if (status == null) {
        status = LinkNodeStatus.ERROR;
    }
    return status;
}

// check server link is it exist or not
/* this method gives fake errors
public LinkNodeStatus ping () {

    boolean reachable = false;
    String sanitizeUrl = url.replaceFirst("^https", "http");

    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(sanitizeUrl).openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(1000);
        connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.err.println(url + " " + responseCode);
        reachable = (200 <= responseCode && responseCode <= 399);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
    }
    return reachable?LinkNodeStatus.OK: LinkNodeStatus.ERROR;
}*/


public String getIpAdress() {
    return ipAdress;
}

public void setIpAdress(String ipAdress) {
    this.ipAdress = ipAdress;
}

/* methods for controlling url size */
public void setSize(int size) {
    this.size = size;
}

public int getSize() {
    return this.size;
}

public void setFileName(String filename) {
    this.filename = filename;
}

public String getFileName() {
    return this.filename;
}

public String getDomain() {
    return domain;
}

public void setDomain(String domain) {
    this.domain = domain;
    }
}
```

**IpFromUrl.java**

```java
package pkg.crawler;

import java.lang.ref.SoftReference;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class IpFromUrl {
static Map<String, String> proccessedDomains = new HashMap();

// Returns the IP address of an URL
// i.e. http://www.facebook.com -> 123.456.789.10
public static String getIp(String hostname) {
    String url = URLWeight.getHostName(hostname);
    if (proccessedDomains.get(url) != null) {
        return proccessedDomains.get(url);
    } else {
        try {
            InetAddress ipaddress = InetAddress.getByName(url);
            System.out.println("IP address of " + url + ": " + ipaddress.getHostAddress());
            proccessedDomains.put(url, ipaddress.getHostAddress());
            return ipaddress.getHostAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not find IP address for: " + url);
            return "";
            // throw new IOException("Could not find IP address for: " +
            // hostname);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(IpFromUrl.getIp("www.google.com"));
    System.out.println(IpFromUrl.getIp("http://www.iaeng.org/IMECS2015/ICDMA2015.html"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Focusing on the more generic review tasks...

**WebCrawler.java**

```
private static Integer cntIntra = new Integer (0);
private static Integer cntInter = new Integer (0);
private static Integer dub = new Integer (0);
```

I will suggest making these [`AtomicInteger`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) instead, so that you do not need to `synchronize` on the fields explicitly before using them.

```
webCrawler.processQueue();
webCrawler.out.close();
webCrawler.err.close();
```

Consider putting these into a single `shutdown()` method?

Your `getOutputLine()` and `generateHeaderFile()` methods seem to be extremely verbose... consider simplifying them further? For starters, you can already do a `.append(field).append(',')` per 'line'. BTW, you also have one minor type: `"Dublications"` should be `"Duplications"`.

**HTMLParser.java**

Not sure why you have an `if (true)` block inside the `parse()` method. Also, in `toLinkNodeObject()`:

```
if(url!=null && url.trim().length()>0) {
    // ...
}
```

That can be *slightly* better written as:

```
if (url!=null && !url.trim().isEmpty()) {
    // ...
}
```

**Util.java**

Since you are already using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), you should use its utilities methods to calculate the differences in milliseconds/seconds/minutes between two `DateTime` instances. Actually, are you using `DateTime` classes consistently, or do you really have a mixture of `Date` objects as well? I suggest sticking with Joda-Time if your solution is < Java 8.

Also, `linkToString()` and `linkToErrorString()` doesn't appear to be used, so consider removing them. Even if you require a `String` representation in the future, consider overriding the method `LinkNode.toString()`.

**URLWeight.java**

I am not too sure how robust your `getHostName()` and `getDomainName()` methods are, so I can only briefly suggest creating unit tests to ensure they work as they should. You also do not require `String domainName = new String(url);`, just `String domainName = url` will do.

**PingTaskManager.java**

The class `PingTaks` seems to be spelled wrongly, and it's also not used in conjunction with `PingTaskManager`.

**LinkNodeLight.java**

```
public int compareTo(LinkNodeLight link) {
    if (this.weight < link.weight) return 1;
     else if (this.weight > link.weight) return -1;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Besides the fact that you are using braces inconsistently, this method can be entirely replaced by [`Float.compareTo(float, float)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#compare-float-float-):

```
public int compareTo(LinkNodeLight link) {
    return Float.compare(link.weight, this.weight);
}
```

Another thing to note about `compareTo()` is that its [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-) only mentions the return value of a positive integer, `0`, or a negative integer. I hope you have not hard-coded comparisons of the return value to `[-1, 1]`.

**IpFromUrl.java**

```
public static String getIp(String hostname) {
    String url = URLWeight.getHostName(hostname);
    if (proccessedDomains.get(url) != null) {
        return proccessedDomains.get(url);
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You do not need the `else` clause here, reducing one level of indentation:

```
public static String getIp(String hostname) {
    String url = URLWeight.getHostName(hostname);
    if (proccessedDomains.get(url) != null) {
        return proccessedDomains.get(url);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Jprofiler is your friend here. After running it for a minute the biggest object in heap is the queue in WebCrawler, and it keeps growing.

[image]

Put a sysout in the enque or deque, printing the size of the queue, and you should see that the size is rocketing up much faster than the 5 threads can deal with.

Maybe you should use files to maintain your queue,

```
let current_file = seed_file
let temp_file = new file
while should_continue_crawling:
  for link in current_file:
    dump all found links for link to temp_file
  current_file = temp_file
  temp_file = new file
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i have a question. How can i store a PriorityQueue content from memory to a disk with keeping high performance for the program. I think when i store on a file it performance will get down than before. Is there anything can help to get same speed for crawling ?

Comment: If you are bottlenecked on retrieving html you might not need a high perf queue.

Comment: Sorry i did not get you. Can you explain in more details please ? @roby

Comment: Im saying that optimizing the queue might not matter if the overwhelming majority of time is spent on network io.

Answer (score 2):

> When I run the program for more than 3 hours, the program runs out of
>   memory. I should run the program for more that 2-3 days non-stop to
>   get the results I need. How is this program using memory
>   inefficiently?

Not a Java developer so I'm not going into the nitty gritty of how to improve code.  That said, the problem sounds pretty simple to be - you're using too much memory.

As such, I can think of two obvious solutions:

1. Don't store as much.  What exactly are you trying to retrieve vs.
   what you are currently retrieving and keeping in memory.
2. Store things better.  If you want to store lots of data (which is
       fine) it makes sense to use a database!  That way it can take a care of managing RAM vs DISK, providing fast querying etc.

Whatever you do, it's a very good idea to build a testing environment that lets you quickly test different strategies and collect key metrics (pages/s, CPU usage, disk usage, memory usage) so that you can make informed decisions focusing on raw performance and scaling.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
1. I am try to retrieve links and its properties like: Score, No.Of links in given current seed, PriorityQueue size, IP address of seeds and etc. 

2. How can i store a PriorityQueue content from memory to a disk with keeping high performance for the program. I think when i store on a file it performance will get down than before. Is there anything can help to get same speed for crawling ?

Comment: "I think when i store on a file it performance will get down than before."  How so?  A algorithm would be something like download webpage (e.g. 100KB) @ 10Mbps connection, take a few key values (e.g. 1KB) and store on HDD @ 1000Mbps.  In short, you should be storing data at a rate 10,000x that you can retrieve it.

Comment: I think there is a mistake by me. By meaning of store memory on a file, i mean dumping PriorityQueue contents (The URLs That Are Not Crawled Yet and Waiting its Turn To Dequeue and Store on File). My question is: If i dumped PriorityQueue contents to a file and reads the Priority from a file (Or Load The Queue From a File), Can this affects program speed ? Foe now I am reading URLs Priority from the Queue (from memory) and when its crawled i am storing it on a .csv file.@NPSF3000

Comment: @medo0070 "i mean dumping PriorityQueue contents (The URLs That Are Not Crawled Yet and Waiting its Turn To Dequeue and Store on File" So all you need to store is a few strings, and then retrieve them?  MongoDB for example can handle tens of thousands of such requests a second.  How fast are you processing them in your application?  Do the maths.

Comment: I am getting average with 300-500urls per minutes. If i used MySQL or MongoDB can i get same speed? And which DB is fast reading than the other ?

Comment: @medo0070 either should be far faster than you need - particularly if you tune it right (you're not interested so much in crash-tolerant data store as speed).  I quite like MongoDB's way of reasoning about data and the C# drivers (I assume Java's are also good), but it's mostly personal preference.

Comment: So there is no DB bunchmarks available?

Comment: @medo0070 there's a lovely chap I'd like you to meet!  His name is google!

Comment: Hhhh ok :D I was wondering to no as your experance which one is better. But no problem i will googling it

Comment: @medo0070 A database would surely help and so would an external file (but a DB is probably better). You can still use a queue for a few requests in the nearest future and only use the DB for the others (refill the queue when it gets nearly empty). Or use the DB alone. I'm pretty sure that there will be no measurable timing difference as you can with a single query taking a few milliseconds get work for the next hour.

Comment: I hope it help me to get avoiding memory crashing again. I will try your suggestion. Thank you very much :) @maaartinus